# Working with null values in Google BigQuery using Talend Big Data

Tags: google-bigquery, talend

I am working on Google BigQuery and it seems that it doesn't accept null values.
So I replaced them with 0s. The problem occurred when calculating average.

For example, consider this file,

---

A|B|C|D

India|1|4|6

Sri Lanka|8||4

Nepal|3|0|6

---

Now say, I have to take average of B,C & D: (B+C+D)/3

Now for row with India, this will work fine. (1+4+6)/3

For row with Nepal, (3+0+6)/3

But for row with Sri Lanka, it should be (8+4)/2

But I am replacing null with 0, thus calculation becoming (8+0+4)/3. Which is wrong.

If I replace null with 0s, it gives wrong output.

How do I make things to work such that nulls are ignored while 0s are counted?

Comment: Let's focus first to find out why NULL values are not working for you, as they should work. Can you share your schema?

Comment: I don't have a specific schema, but for upcoming work.  I have predicted such a scenario,,, Thus created small demonstration of data file.

Comment: Without schema, this is a bad question, as with correct schema you don't have this issue, and no need to demonstrate a wrong approach side effect.

Comment: I'm with pentium10 here..... Null values WORK in BigQuery. Why do you say they don't?

Answer (score 3):

A mix of integers and NULL values will work fine for a field with "integer" type and "nullable" node, but not if the mode is "required" (since this disallows NULL values).

Note that when importing data as CSV, NULL values are represented by an empty field, not by the string "NULL" nor like "\N".

Comment: I am using Google Bigquery, here null are represented by "\n".

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri I don't think so "\n" represents null, you should leave the field empty, than it's NULL.